# Can loaders be used without content provider or combination is must?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loader

1. Can loaders be used without content provider or combination is must?
2. Is it best practice to use content provider only when it is intended
   to use by other applications or for only local use also content
   provider is recommended?
3. If data updated in SQLite, Will loader deliver updated data, if not used with content provider?

I have tried to find convincing answers to above questions, but could not find it. Please help.

Comment: `LoaderManager` works with `Loader`s, not only with `CursorLoader`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A Loader is a way to load information for your activity/fragment without performing the computation on the UI thread. It can be used with a Content provider or you can use a subclass of Loader/AsyncTaskLoader to access data of your own choosing. You can find more info on how and when to use a Loader [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#app).
2. It is best practice to use a content provider to access data when a content provider is available. They are maintained by the system and are a good way to ensure the consistency of the data provided. You can create your own content provider to provide data from one application to another. More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).
3. You can create a loader for an sqlite database by follwing the info in this guide at section 7 [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider).

Comment: If data updated in SQLite, Will loader deliver updated data, if not used with content provider?

Comment: @DarshanKapasi sure, provided you call `ContentResolver#notifyChange` where needed

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your edit to the question.

Comment: Thank you @JWhitfield for your answer, but my 3rd question is not answered in your answer. I want to know, If data updated in SQLite from background service/thread, Will loaders deliver updated data, **if i have not used with content provider?** Please do the needful.

Comment: @pskink, thank you for your reply. You mean we need not to use `ContentResolver#notifyChange` is not required when content providers are used. if Yes, Why?

Comment: @DarshanKapasi no in ContentProvider you need to use it as well, like [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/app/activity/LocalProvider.java) or [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/cts/tests/tests/content/src/android/content/cts/DummyProvider.java)

Comment: @pskink thank you for your answer. if i use ContentResolver's insert/update and delete method to update db then is there a need to use `ContentResolver#notifyChange`?